Is leaving bicycle outdoors short term okay without signs of decay?
I sometimes leave my bicycle outside and it rains sometimes it is left in the rain for a day or few or ridden in the rain and washed with a hose with soap and water. Is that bad for my bicycle as many people say that rain or water will instantly ruin a bicycle but in my case its been years of such practice and there is no rust or other form of decay. Is this alright? my bicycle is primary stored in a shed or garage.

Sounds like you are doing it right. Many people have an unhealthy emotional attachment to their bike remaining pristine, others see a bike as a utility object that is there to be used and abused. Most on this site sit in the middle ground, worthy of looking after them, but they are to be used. This leads to lots of strong opinions on subjects like this, and for some people the cosmetic damage caused is bad.
Ideally you would not leave the bike out, but if it cannot be avoided occasionally it is not the end of the world. It will not hurt the bike mechanically. The bike might get a bit of cosmetic surface rust that it might not otherwise get, but occasionally leaving it in the rain for a day or two will not hurt it more than riding it in the rain.
Main damage is actually done when the bike is dirty and stored wet or in a damp environment, especially if salt (coastal climates or from winter roads) is involved. The dirt holds the moisture and absorbs it from the atmosphere. The more humid the climate, the worse.
